# apexchart with covid-19 map throws an error

Tags: javascript, html, apexcharts

Im using `apexchart` to draw a `covid-19 map` but for some reason when I changed the link of the json I was using it showed an error message

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Choropleth Map</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.7.1/js/anychart-core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.7.1/js/anychart-map.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.7.1/geodata/custom/world/world.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.15/proj4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.7.1/js/anychart-data-adapter.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            html,
            body,
            #container {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script>

            anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

                // load the data
                anychart.data.loadJsonFile("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json/", function (data) {

                    // Variables
                    // go into the records section of the data
                    var geoData = data.records

                    // sum of all cases per country
                    var sumCases = 0;

                    // sum of all deaths per country
                    var sumDeaths = 0;

                    // convert cases and deaths to numbers
                    var numC;
                    var numD;

                    // create a new array with the resulting data
                    var data = [];

                    // Go through the initial data
                    for (var i = 0; i < geoData.length; i++) {
                        // convert strings to numbers and save them to new variables
                        numC = parseInt(geoData[i].cases);
                        numD = parseInt(geoData[i].deaths);

                        // check if we are in the same country by comparing the geoId. 
                        // if the country is the same add the cases and deaths to the appropriate variables
                        if ((geoData[i + 1]) != null && (geoData[i].geoId == geoData[i + 1].geoId)) {
                            sumCases = sumCases + numC;
                            sumDeaths = sumDeaths + numD;
                        }
                        else {
                            // add last day cases and deaths of the same country
                            sumCases = sumCases + numC;
                            sumDeaths = sumDeaths + numD;

                            // insert the resulting data in the array using the AnyChart keywords 
                            data.push({ id: geoData[i].geoId, value: sumCases, size: sumDeaths, title: geoData[i].countriesAndTerritories })

                            // reset the variables to start over
                            sumCases = 0;
                            sumDeaths = 0;

                        }
                    };

                    // connect the data with the map
                    var chart = anychart.map(data);
                    chart.geoData(anychart.maps.world);

                    // specify the chart type and set the series 
                    var series = chart.choropleth(data);

                    // variable to store data that will be used for bubbles
                    var bubbleData = [];

                    // store only the countries that have at least 1 death
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if (data[i].size > 0) {
                            bubbleData.push(data[i]);
                        }
                    };

                    // create a series for bubbles
                    var series_1 = chart.bubble(bubbleData);

                    // set the maximum size of the bubble
                    chart.maxBubbleSize(25);

                    // set the minimum size of the bubble
                    chart.minBubbleSize(3);

                    // set colors and stroke of bubbles
                    series_1.normal().fill("black", 0.3);
                    series_1.hovered().fill("black", 0.1);
                    series_1.selected().fill("black", 0.5);
                    series_1.normal().stroke("rgb(150,33,31)");
                    series_1.hovered().stroke("rgb(150,33,31)", 2);
                    series_1.selected().stroke("rgb(150,33,31)", 4);

                    // set the chart title
                    chart.title("COVID-19 Global Cases");

                    // color scale ranges
                    ocs = anychart.scales.ordinalColor([
                        { less: 99 },
                        { from: 100, to: 999 },
                        { from: 1000, to: 9999 },
                        { from: 10000, to: 29999 },
                        { from: 30000, to: 39000 },
                        { from: 40000, to: 59000 },
                        { from: 60000, to: 99999 },
                        { greater: 100000 }
                    ]);

                    // set scale colors
                    ocs.colors(["rgb(252,245,245)", "rgb(241,219,216)", "rgb(229,190,185)", "rgb(211,152,145)", "rgb(192,117,109)", "rgb(178,93,86)", "rgb(152,50,48)", "rgb(150,33,31)"]);

                    // tell the series what to use as a colorRange (colorScale)
                    series.colorScale(ocs);

                    // enable the legend
                    chart.legend(true);

                    // set the source mode of the legend and add styles
                    chart.legend()
                        .itemsSourceMode("categories")
                        .position('right')
                        .align('top')
                        .itemsLayout('vertical')
                        .padding(50, 0, 0, 20)
                        .paginator(false);

                    // tooltip formatting
                    series.tooltip().format("Total Confirmed Cases: {%value}");
                    series_1.tooltip().format("Total Deaths: {%size}");

                    // set the container id
                    chart.container('container');

                    // draw the chart
                    chart.draw();
                });


            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

The error messages that it was showing me are:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json/download.json'
> from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.
>
> opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/json/download.json:1
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

My question is what am I missing in my code that needs to be added for it work because it worked with a different api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: There are no CORS headers in the response so it fails, you can't get the data directly using ajax

Comment: How will I be add the CORS header ?

Comment: I have also tried the link above but it resulted in more errors